# Python with luminati cannot connect to proxie

Tags: python

I'm trying to use proxies from luminati website with Selenium. When browsers open it shows "No internet accesses". I cannot figure out what I've been doing wrong.

```
username = 'lum-customer-hx_185d159x-zone-static-route_err-pass_dyn'
password = 'xxxxxx'
port = 22225
session_id = random.random()
super_proxy_url = ('http://%s-session-%s:%s@zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:%d' %
                   (username, session_id, password, port))
proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({
    'http': super_proxy_url,
    'https': super_proxy_url,
})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler)
proxy_details = opener.open('http://lumtest.com/myip.json').read()
data = json.loads(proxy_details)


PROXY = data['ip']+":"+"22225"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=chrome_binary_path(), options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)

driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Luminati Proxy Manager up and running on the machine where your code is running.